# htaccess / custom 404 page - everything seem to be fine, but it does not work (frustrated)

Tags: php, .htaccess

```
<Files ~ "^\.(htaccess|htpasswd)$">
    deny from all
</Files>
Options Indexes
ErrorDocument 404 new404.html 
order deny,allow
```

- File is without name just with extension .thaccess
- It is in the main domain folder with index page and others.
- New 404 page is called new404.html and it is in the same folder as htaccess file.

I checked the code with few guides on the htaccess topic, and it seem to be fine.

I will appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: If the file name is `.thaccess` and that wasn't a typo, I've found your problem. Also, please add line breaks in your code.

Comment: The main configuration (usually under `/etc/apache2/`): Does it allow `.htaccess` files? Also, the file name of new404.html must start with a `/`: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#ErrorDocument

Comment: Thanks guys, but I don't know much about those kind of coding. I will appreciate if you will talk to me like to caveman, and show me how the code should to look like. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't write in one line must be

```
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 404 new404.html
<Files ~ "^\.(htaccess|htpasswd)$">
    deny from all 
</Files>
```